# JavaScript: Implementing Callback Functions

Tags: javascript

This is a three part question.

In the code shown below, whenever I execute the functions (walk, run, crawl) I am observing that it is displaying the output for the method distance_travelled in a cumulative manner:

**Trey says thank you 

Trey walked a distance of 3 

Trey ran a distance of 13 

Trey crawled a distance of 16 

Trey ran a distance of 26**

I would like to ensure that each function calculates the distance by considering the method distance_travelled to be initialized to **0**.

My second question is related to the callback function.

I am trying to create another property/method called doSomething() and have this method return a random function back (walk, run, crawl).

For example if I execute the following code:

```
var returned_function = person.doSomething(); 
returned_function();
```

It should execute one of the three methods. I have managed to execute the method **run()**. However, when I run the code in my browser, the alert pop up message displays **undefined**. Also, I encounter the same issue as in my first question. It calculates distance_travelled in a cumulative manner. How can I solve this?

My third question. I am trying to add a new method called '**fly**' to the **person** object. The 'fly' method takes two functions as arguments.

I have to give a 30% chance for the person to fly. The function fly method should execute if the person is successfully able to fly (30% chance that this can happen). The second function  should execute if the person is NOT able to fly (70% chance this would happen).

How can I implement this functionality into my code? Can someone suggest how to approach this problem?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var person = new Object();

    person.name = "Trey";
    person.distance_travelled = 0;
    person.say_name = alert(person.name);

    person.say_something = function(xyz) {
        document.write(person.name + " says " + xyz + '<br>');
    }
    person.say_something("thank you");

    person.walk = alert(person.name + " is walking");
    function walk(){
        person.distance_travelled +=3;
        document.write(person.name + " walked a distance of " + person.distance_travelled + '<br>');
    }
    walk();

    person.run = alert(person.name + " is running");
    function run(){
        person.distance_travelled +=10;
        document.write(person.name + " ran a distance of " + person.distance_travelled + '<br>');
    }
    run();

    person.crawl = alert(person.name + " is crawling");
    function crawl(){
        person.distance_travelled +=3;
        document.write(person.name + " crawled a distance of " + person.distance_travelled + '<br>');
    }
    crawl();

    person.doSomething = function(abc){
        alert(run());
    }
    var returned_function = person.doSomething();
    returned_function();


</script>
```

Comment: This is a really long and specific question. If it's a "three part question" why not ask three smaller actions? Questions with a lot of lines of code are hardly ever applicable to other users again in the future.

Comment: Ok, will trim it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all:

```
    person.walk = alert(person.name + " is walking");
```

probably does nothing like what you think it would (because I can't ever think a line like that might make sense).

---

Your first question is trivial. If you want to output `3`, just output `3`, not `distance_travelled`.

Second question:

```
var activities = ['run', 'walk', 'crawl'];
person.doSomething = function() {
    var randomActivity = activities[Math.floor(Math.random() * activities.length)];
    return function() {
        this[randomActivity]();
    }   
}
var personDoActivity = person.doSomething();
personDoActivity();
```

or

```
person.doSomething = function() {
    var activities = [this.run, this.walk, this.crawl];
    var randomActivity = activities[Math.floor(Math.random() * activities.length)];
    return randomActivity;
}
var doActivity = person.doSomething();
doActivity.call(person);
```

Third question (and I'm changing it from object-oriented to procedural because you're not using OO correctly, anyway):

```
function maybeFly(fly, noFly) {
    if (Math.random() < 0.3) {
        return fly();
    } else {
        return noFly();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Amadan, thanks for the response. With regard to the person.walk variable, I simply put it because the problem I am working required me to output that variable in the specific manner. As you said rightly, it is of no consequence.

With regard to the first question, I was trying to reduce the amount of code being reused, hence, I was using the distance_travelled variable.

Thanks for clarifying the remaining questions as well. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because I still can't comment on answers -.-

@Amadan

the second version of doSomething can maybe be even nicer using .bind()

```
person.doSomething = function() {
    var activities = [this.run, this.walk, this.crawl];
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * activities.length);

    return activities[randomIndex].bind(this);
}
var doActivity = person.doSomething();
doActivity();
```

Also worth noting that it is better to use, and more in the spirit of javascript to write

```
var person = {};
```

instead of

```
var person = new Object();
```